# Image Won't Center Properly

Tags: html, css, debugging

I can't seem to get a bit of code to work.  Slightly embarrassed since it should be pretty simple.  Long story short, I'm trying to get an image to center and it's not cooperating.  The relevant code follows.

Thank you much

HTML:

```
<div class="Room">

    <div class="Wall">
        <img src="Rooms/NorthBlank.JPG" border="0" />
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.Room {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
border: none;
position: fixed;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
}

.Wall {
display: block;
margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: I don't see your "relevant code".

Comment: text-align:center in your CSS will centre an image.

Comment: Yeah, sorry.  Hit enter too quick.  Code is now included.

Comment: `text-align:center;` in your `.Wall` class will center it

Comment: Text-align: center; didn't work.

Comment: Add width:100% to Room, and add text-align:center to Wall, and make sure that your img tag is display:inline or display:inline-block

Comment: @user2377660 , yes it did! but if the space on the wall is the same size as the image, it's always "centered"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the fixed div a width of 100% and then add `text-align:center` to the inner div.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/vmWLB/)**

```
.Room {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width:100%;
}
.Wall {
    margin: auto;
    text-align:center;
}
```